# Number of clocks consumed by same functions changes drastically depending on its order of execution

Tags: c, linux

I was trying to measure the clock cycles consumed by sequential search in c.

```
int seqsearch(int arr[], int n, int val){
    for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
        if(arr[i] == val)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

void main(){
    int arr[20000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 20000; i++){
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    int search = 17777;
    double time;
    clock_t start, end, consumed;
    start = clock();
    printf("\nSearch for %d :%d\n", search, seqsearch(arr, 20000, search));
    end = clock();
    consumed = end - start;
    printf("\nNo. of clocks consumed = %ld\n", consumed);
    time = (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nRuntime = %lf\n", time);
    start= clock();
    printf("\nSearch for %d :%d\n", search, seqsearch(arr, 20000, search));
    end = clock();
    consumed = end - start;
    printf("\nNo.of clocks consumed:%ld\n", consumed);
    time = (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nRuntime:%lf\n", time);
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out

Search for 17777 :17777

No. of clocks consumed = 339

Runtime = 0.000000

Search for 17777 :17777

No.of clocks consumed:177

Runtime:0.000000
```

Every time I execute it the cock cycles consumed in second execution is much lesser than those consumed in the first. If I am executing same function twice at nearly the same time shouldn't both executions take nearly the same clock cycles.

Comment: Can you say 'cache'?  What time do you get on a third try?

Comment: Note that you get zero as the time because the calculation is done using integer arithmetic and the time is less than one second so the division yields zero, which is dutifully converted to a double value of zero.  Cast at least one of the terms to `double`.

Comment: Or, instead of casting, you could add 0.0 to the subtraction : `time = (0.0 + end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;` (or just : `time = (entime = (0.0+consumed )/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;` )

Comment: Note you are also timing `printf` so it would be better to store the return value from `seqsearch` in a variable and move `printf` outside the `clock()` calls.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce your original result (with a minor tweak to print the time correctly): https://ideone.com/ilQcmU.

Then I made a version that didn't time the call to `printf`, since that's slow and unrelated to the thing you're timing: https://ideone.com/gVC01c.

```
...
int result;
start = clock();
result = seqsearch(arr,20000,search);
end = clock();
printf("\nSearch for %d :%d\n",search, result);
consumed = end - start;
printf("No. of clocks consumed = %ld\n",consumed);
time = (double)consumed/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("Runtime = %lf\n",time);
...
```

The second printout was modified in the same way. Results show that that's likely to be your culprit:

```
Search for 17777 :17777
No. of clocks consumed = 10
Runtime = 0.000010

Search for 17777 :17777
No.of clocks consumed:9
Runtime:0.000009
```

Then I stuck the whole thing into a loop, to check if caching was having a noticeable effect: https://ideone.com/xYsL5x.

```
...
int result, i;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    start = clock();
    result = seqsearch(arr,20000,search);
    end = clock();
    printf("\nSearch for %d :%d\n",search, result);
    consumed = end - start;
    printf("No. of clocks consumed = %ld\n",consumed);
    time = (double)consumed/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Runtime = %lf\n",time);
}
...
```

It does not look like caching is at fault here, but with that timing resolution, it's hard to say for sure. It is clearly unimportant even if it does have an effect.

For completeness, I put the printout back into your timing within the loop: https://ideone.com/HnYkVd.

```
...
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    start = clock();
    printf("\nSearch for %d :%d\n",search, seqsearch(arr,20000,search));
    end = clock();
...
```

Here, there is a clearly visible startup effect. I don't think it's necessarily caching though. I think it's more likely to be buffer reallocation by the print mechanism than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

What you are observing here is the effect of caching. Data accessed by `seqsearch` gets cached when you call the function first time. During the second call of `seqsearch` (most if not all) the data would already be available in the cache. This results in faster access and hence the reduced time.
You can validate this by adding a third call to this function which should result in almost equal time as the second call.

Comment: My immediate reaction was cache, but…the code to initialize the array should have done the caching, shouldn't it?

Comment: Could be L1 cache smaller than array size.

Comment: I think @WeatherVane has nailed it in a comment.  The difference is due to setup work in `printf()` being included in the timing.  And the time is exaggerated because `printf()` is included in the timing.

Comment: I've tried running it both ways. Pretty sure it's not caching.

Answer (score 1):

You should mesure the elapsed time before calling printf. You currently include printf and its side effects in the timing